# SSRS, chart Title.... can I format part of title differently (color, style). Use \x00B0C chars

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssrs-2012

I'm trying and learning how to make my chart title meet specs, so need to **BOLD**  some words in title, put diff color for some words, use special html chars into it....
For now I learned in hard way that I can't do this (note that chart title works differently then text in SSRS text box).

Do you  think  it's still possible? let say do this in my title?
THIS IS MY CHART TITLE IN BOLD AND THIS TEXT IS RED COLOR, this DEGREE SIGN \X00BO.....
My report is kinda of dashboard style, it has only chart that's it, nothing else is permited, no headers, no tablix..

I found  this greate resource here http://support2.dundas.com/forum/tm.aspx?m=3028&mpage=1&key=&#3039  and it's didn't help me in chart title.
Tx all
M

Comment: I am not sure of this but did you try to create a placeholder and set html as markup type in general tab?

Comment: You can not make placeholder in chart title, I tried, also I think you can not resize/move title box.

Comment: I see. Maybe it would be better if you delete the chart title and put a textbox above (wherever you want your title). If you want to have chart and title in a rectangle set chart border to none and move the chart and textbox inside a rectangle component and set border.

Comment: Tx, yes I put text box above the chart where I can do all formatting

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has this problem, you can add more than one title to a chart and format them differently.  So if you need a **Big Bold Title** with a smaller summary/descriptive line underneath you would require two independently formatted titles.